# Database link between Oracle and Informix

Tags: database, oracle, replication, informix, database-link

It is possible to create a database link between Oracle and Informix which will allow for replication?

Has anyone done this before?  Any ideas? 
Please help me....

Comment: Haven't done this but you probably need a ODBC driver for informix and setup a HS ODBC connection in Oracle (called Oracle database gateway in 11G). Search the internet with this terminology.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Oracle Database Gateways for Informix` which is based on `Oracle Heterogenous Services` to creat a link between Oracle and Informix.

Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/gateways.112/e12066/intro.htm) (corresponds to Oracle 11gR2) for details and case studies.

Comment: @thebrave. With Oracle Gateway you can configure using the Informix native access our thru ODBC. AFAIK, the ODBC option don't require license (it's free), but if you use the specific Informix configuration then you need to license your environment. You can check this at the [Oracle Price List](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/technology-price-list-070617.pdf)